# how to get all members under me in mysql SQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql

In MySQL SQL Stored Procedures, I need to retrieve all referrals under me at all levels while using where under referrals gives one level only

*Sample Data*

| Name | Referred By |
| --- | --- |
| Alice |  |
| Bob | Alice |
| Carol | Alice |
| Dave | Bob |
| Eve | Bob |
| Frank | Carol |
| Grace | Eve |
| Helen |  |
| David | Helen |
| Lucas | David |
| Olivia | Lucas |
| Sophia | Lucas |
| Benjamin | Bob |

Expected Result
I asked for 'Alice' all level referrals then i need like this

- Bob
- Carol
- Dave
- Eve
- Frank
- Grace
- Benjamin

where these shouldn't display (David,Lucas,Olivia ,Sophia) is no way related to Alice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE name = ?
    -- or, if initial person shouldn't be returned,
    -- WHERE referred_by = ?
  UNION ALL
    SELECT table.*
    FROM table
    JOIN cte ON cte.name = table.referred_by
)
SELECT name
FROM cte
```

Comment: Hi, its ok but result as per above code is Alice,Bob,Carol,Dave,Eve,Frank,Benjamin,Grace but expected result need is  `Bob,Carol,Dave,Eve,Frank,Grace,Benjamin` , in order of creation which can used on order_by  in cte  and for Alice referral Alice cant be listed . Right?  How to ignore  Alice?

Comment: @geroge *How to ignore Alice?* Obviously `WHERE referred_by = ?`..

Comment: @Akina Thank you. This is the best way I believe. But in case window functions are not available, a subpar option is to use a procedure. I made one and the experience was tiresome. I was wondering if it's possible to get the job done using neither window functions nor stored procedure ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo *But in case window functions are not available* ?? My query does not use window function. It uses CTE. *if it's possible to get the job done using neither window functions nor stored procedure* If your MySQL version is 5+, then the best way is version upgrade. If this is not an option then the task cannot be solved without stored procedure (or user-defined function). As a palliative you may alter or expand the table schema and add fully qualified path column.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I had always thought CTE was a form of window function. So as I suspected, SQL has its limitations in certain tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive cte is really convenient and should be strongly recommended. However, the job can be accomplished without one by using a stored procedure, which requires temporary tables. Only do it when recursive CTE is out of reach. i.e mysql version 5.x and below.

```
select * from the test;
+----------+-------------+
| Name     | Referred_by |
+----------+-------------+
| Alice    |             |
| Bob      | Alice       |
| Carol    | Alice       |
| Dave     | Bob         |
| Eve      | Bob         |
| Frank    | Carol       |
| Grace    | Eve         |
| Helen    |             |
| David    | Helen       |
| Lucas    | David       |
| Olivia   | Lucas       |
| Sophia   | Lucas       |
| Benjamin | Bob         |
+----------+-------------+

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists test_proc //
create procedure test_proc(leader varchar(10))
begin
drop temporary table if exists tmp; 
drop temporary table if exists result;
create temporary table tmp (name varchar(10)); -- tmp stores names of leaders (aka referred_by in this case) for one recursive cycle
create temporary table result(name varchar(10), is_new bool default 1); -- result stores names of people referred by the leaders. The newly added names are also appointed as new leaders and to be moved to the tmp table.

insert result (name) select name from test where referred_by=leader; -- the very same names referred by the original leader are also to be recorded here
insert tmp select name from result where is_new=1; -- Get the names which are referred by the original leader.  The IN argument from the procedure is passed here. Alice is going to be used as the original leader in the test. Note, the WHERE clause in the query is superfluous for the first recursive round.

UPDATE result SET is_new = 0; -- once the names are moved to tmp , they should be set to the status as used (no longer qualifed as leader candidates)

while exists (select 1 from tmp) do -- as long as there is one instance(leader) in tmp, the recursive cycles go on 

insert result (name) 
select name from test where referred_by in (select name from tmp) -- get the names referred by the leaders into the result table
;


DELETE FROM tmp; -- clean up the current leaders' list
insert tmp (select `name` from result where is_new=1); -- get the NEW leaders from the result table
UPDATE result SET is_new = 0 WHERE is_new = 1; -- change the status in the result table so the names won't be moved to the tmp again

end while; 

SELECT name FROM result; -- displays the result table after recursive job is done

end//

delimiter ;
```

Let's test it using `alice` as the original leader:

```
call test_proc('alice');

+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| Bob      |
| Carol    |
| Dave     |
| Eve      |
| Frank    |
| Benjamin |
| Grace    |
+----------+
```

Try `helen` this time:

```
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| David  |
| Lucas  |
| Olivia |
| Sophia |
+--------+
```

To put it in a nutshell, it's possible to perform a recursive job without using a recursive CTE. But the coding is tedious. Should only do it when CTE is not available, and only as a last resort.